# angularjs component dynamic filter

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, filter, components, angularjs-1.6

If the name of the filter is static, you can just inject the name of the filter with "Filter" appended to it into your component's controller function, like this:

```
angular.module('ngApp').component('myComponent', {
    bindings: {
        dynamicFilter: '@'
    },
    controller: [
        'staticFilterFilter',
        function(staticFilterFilter) {
            this.valueSetByStaticFilter = staticFilterFilter('x');
        }]
});
```

Is there a way to pass the name of a filter into an angularjs version 1.6 component as bound as argument/attribute string using '@' and then be able to get that filter by name and use it inside of the controller of that component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject the **[$filter service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter)** into the component's Controller. You can then retrieve and use the filter by doing something like this:

```
var filtered = $filter('yourFilterName')(arg1,arg2);
```

So in your code change it to something like:

```
angular.module('ngApp').component('myComponent', {
    bindings: {
        dynamicFilter: '@'
    },
    controller: [
        '$filter',
        function($filter) {
            var filtered = $filter(this.dynamicFilter)(arg1,arg2);
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried something like that earlier and was getting an error. But it actually does work for me, thanks.

Comment: Good Stuff! Pleased it helped.